# Python-OpenCv FindContours

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I try to find contours in a binary image but when try to execute cvFindContours it gives me that error message

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "convert.py", line 30, in
>   
>       contour = cvFindContours(img2, storage, cv.CV_RETR_CCOMP, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)   File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/opencv/cv.py", line 580, in
>   cvFindContours
>       count, seq = cvFindContoursUntyped( *args )   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/opencv/cv.py", line 6521, in
>   cvFindContoursUntyped
>       return _cv.cvFindContoursUntyped(*args) RuntimeError:  openCV Error:
>           Status=Incorrect size of input array
>           function name=cvStartFindContours
>           error message=
>           file_name=/build/buildd/opencv-2.1.0/src/cv/cvcontours.cpp
>           line=205

I using fresh installed Ubuntu 11.10 and Opencv 2.3.1.

Here is my source code

```
from opencv.cv import *
from opencv.highgui import *

image = cvLoadImage('test.png')
def getthresholdedimg(image):
    size = cvSize(640, 480)

    imghsv=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image),8,3)
    cvCvtColor(image,imghsv,cv.CV_BGR2HSV)
    imgblue=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image),8,1)
    imgblue2=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image),8,1)
    imgthreshold=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image),8,1)

    cvInRangeS(imghsv,cvScalar(100,100,100),cvScalar(120,255,255),imgblue)
    cvInRangeS(imghsv,cvScalar(100,100,100),cvScalar(120,255,255),imgblue2)
    cvAdd(imgblue,imgblue,imgthreshold)
    return imgthreshold


cvFlip(image,image,1)

cvSmooth(image, image, CV_GAUSSIAN, 3, 0)
imgthresh=getthresholdedimg(image)
cvErode(imgthresh,imgthresh,None,3)
cvDilate(imgthresh,imgthresh,None,10)
storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0)
img2=cvCloneImage(imgthresh)
contour = cvFindContours(img2, storage, cv.CV_RETR_CCOMP, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

my original and binary image

Original image
http://tinypic.com/r/34rul9x/6

and blue filtered binary image
http://tinypic.com/r/ifbotx/6

Comment: If that error message is complete then it says nothing (why is the input array of incorrect size ?). Simply changing your imports to `from cv import *`, and removing the prefix "cv" from function names and constants, the example works. If I force the use of `FindContours` on an image with multiple channels, then I get: `cv2.error: [Start]FindContours support only 8uC1 and 32sC1 images`. If the API you are using is still supported by OpenCV, fill a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

**Find contours in python cv2**

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2

    img = cv2.imread('sample_image.jpg')
    imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
    _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this style of API is discontinued from OpenCV. Presently two API is there, old one is `cv` obtained by

```
>>> import cv2.cv as cv
```

And the second and new one is the `cv2` available as :

```
>>> import cv2
```

Regarding the error :

Replace import statement with `from cv2.cv import *`

Then remove all the `cv` prefix, it should work fine.

**NOTE :**

I think you are trying for color tracking of objects.

But since you have OpenCV 2.3.1, why do you use very old Python API ?

New Python API is `cv2` version, which is simple, fast and flexible. Also, it is difficult to play with various objects in Old API compared to new API. So I would recommend you to update to new `cv2` API. It is even difficult debug errors in old API.

You can find color tracking code with new `cv2` API in this link : http://goo.gl/db2KW

Or if you are sure to use old API, here is the code : http://goo.gl/AFEmv